# Reverse polish notation algorithm doesn`t work correctly with the same operands

Tags: python, algorithm, polish-notation

I've written polish notation algorithm. But it doesn`t work properly, if there are  the same operands between operator. If we run this code with current list ['a', '+', 'a', '*', 'b'], it will work properly, but if we change(b) on (a) it won't.
The result in the first case is (a, a, b, *, +) and in the second (a, a, +, a, *). Why does it happen?

```
operators = ["+", "-"]
operators1 = ["*", "/"]
operators2 = ["^"]
operators3 = ["(", ")"]
all_operators = ["+", "-", "*", "/", "^"]


def get_priority(operator):
    if operator in operators:
        priority = 1
    if operator in operators1:
        priority = 2
    if operator in operators2:
        priority = 3
    if operator in operators3:
        priority = 4
return priority


def notation():
exit = []
stack = []
list = ['a', '+', 'a', '*', 'b']
for i in list:

    if i not in all_operators:
        exit.append(i)

    else:
        stack.append(i)
        while len(stack) > 1 and get_priority(stack[-2]) >= get_priority(stack[-1]):
            exit.append(stack.pop(-2))

    if i is list[-1]:
        while len(stack) > 0:
            exit.append(stack.pop())

print(exit)
    


notation()
```

Comment: What does "change(b) on (a)" mean?

Comment: When you run your program with a debugger, what is the first thing it does that you didn't expect?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please note that your code as shown is malformed – it has at least two incorrectly indented blocks. Please [edit] your question to enable us to debug your *actual* code. See the [mcve] and [ask] pages how to best help us help you.

Comment: What is `if i is list[-1]:` used for?

Comment: Note that your issue is *probably* due to the ``if i is list[-1]:`` line. This only triggers if the last element is identical to some other element - i.e. in ``['a', '+', 'a', '*', 'a']`` because ``list[0] is list[-1]`` and ``list[2] is list[-1]``. This line likely does not do what you want – ``is`` is the *identity* operator, and the identity of literal values is implementation defined. Did you mean to test whether the ``for`` loop is at the last element?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thank you for your help. I thought that all elements were different objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is `i is list[-1]` and it surfaces when the last element of the list is a value that occurs also earlier in the list. In the case of ['a', '+', 'a', '*', 'a'], the condition will be true on the first iteration of the loop (and the third, and the last). Obviously this will produce wrong results.

As you want to perform that `while` loop only when going through the last iteration of the `for` loop, you might as well move that `while` loop *after* the whole `for` block, and unconditionally.

I applied some other changes to your code that do not relate to your question, and are not fixes to the algorithm itself, but just seem better practice. And I removed the parentheses from the operator list, as your code does not support that feature yet (Polish notation should not include parentheses):

```
operator_priority = {
    "+": 1,
    "-": 1,
    "*": 2,
    "/": 2,
    "^": 3,
}

all_operators = list(operator_priority.keys())

def notation(tokens):
    result = []
    stack = []
    for token in tokens:
        if token not in all_operators:
            result.append(token)
        else:
            prio = operator_priority[token]
            while len(stack) > 0 and operator_priority[stack[-1]] >= prio:
                result.append(stack.pop())
            stack.append(token)
    while len(stack) > 0:
        result.append(stack.pop())
    return result
    
result = notation(['a', '+', 'a', '*', 'a'])
print(result)
```